# Tracking status of notification send by GCM

Tags: android, notifications, google-play-services

I have put tracking on all the user actions performed on the notifications send by the GCM. But i found some abrupt actions. There are many notifications which are neither read nor swiped, but are received on the user device. I could not recognize the reason behind this, because if the notification is received on the device it must be read or swiped. Is there some process in which android system eats up these notification or is there any role of google play services in eating up these notifications. What is the possible reason that user couldn't perform any action on these notifications.

Answer (score 0):

[Notification Actions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Actions) are optional and aside from the ways you mentioned, Android notifications can also be cleared from the device itself by pressing the [clear all](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Removing) button. So you might want to consider notifications without actions as something that was ignored by the user.

Comment: I have tracked the notifications on the "clear all" button also. It is working fine as i have tested it for multiple cases. There is some other issue. Please provide me some other solution.